# Microsoft.Web.Administration null reference when trying to add application to site

Tags: c#, iis

i'm trying to add an application to site via code (C#) and i get a null reference.
someone have an idea why?

here's the code i use:
Application app;

```
using (var sm = new ServerManager())
{
    if (site.Applications["/" + appName] == null)
    {
          site.Applications.Add("/" + appName, physicalPath);
          sm.CommitChanges();
    }
    app = site.Applications["/" + appName];
}
return app;
```

the code fails on the "add" line.
the appName is a string like "MyNewApp".
the physicalPath is a string like "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyService".
the site is Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site object of the IIS6.1 (win 7 ent) default web site.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer: [NullReferenceException in Microsoft.Web.Administration when adding https binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384996/nullreferenceexception-in-microsoft-web-administration-when-adding-https-binding)

its all because of the "using" statement.
the site didn't have a parent ServerManager at the point of the application add.