# Add binding to IIS-site - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add bindings to a website in IIS with C# code. It seem to work on my local computer, but not on the hosting server (Windows Server 2022). Adding http-binding works, but commit after https causes NullReferenceException, and i am wondering if any of you can explain to me why?

My code is like this (i replaced my actual domainname with . "sitename" and "hostHttpsBinding" always exists with the certificate i want to use):

```
public static bool AddBindings(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger, string subdomain)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subdomain)) return false;

        try
        {
            var server = new ServerManager();
            var sitename = EnvironmentHelper.IsProd(configuration) ? "<domain>.no" : "test.<domain>.no";
            var hostname = $"{subdomain.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()}.<domain>.no";

            var site = server.Sites.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == sitename);
            if (site == null) return false;

            logger.LogInformation($"IIS: Sitename {sitename} found. Trying to add bindings...");

            var hostHttpsBinding = site.Bindings.FirstOrDefault(a => a.BindingInformation == $"*:443:{sitename}");
            var httpBinding = site.Bindings.FirstOrDefault(a => a.BindingInformation == $"*:80:{hostname}");
            var httpsBinding = site.Bindings.FirstOrDefault(a => a.BindingInformation == $"*:443:{hostname}");

            if (httpBinding != null && httpsBinding != null) return false;

            if (httpBinding == null)
            {
                site.Bindings.Add($"*:80:{hostname}", "http");

                logger.LogInformation($"IIS: Http-binding added for {hostname}");
            }
            
            if (httpsBinding == null)
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"SSLName: {hostHttpsBinding.CertificateStoreName}, Hash: {hostHttpsBinding.CertificateHash}");
                site.Bindings.Add($"*:443:{hostname}", hostHttpsBinding.CertificateHash, hostHttpsBinding.CertificateStoreName, SslFlags.Sni);
                
                logger.LogInformation($"IIS: Https-binding added for {hostname}");
            }

            server.CommitChanges();
            server.Dispose();

            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError($"IIS: Something went wrong when adding bindings: {e.Message}, {e.InnerException.Message}");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is my error message:

```
ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer|Connection ID "16717361851964326032", Request ID "40000091-0008-e800-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.|System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Is it because you don’t use using statement? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384996/nullreferenceexception-in-microsoft-web-administration-when-adding-https-binding

Comment: Omg, this was totally my bad. Using works, but also i found out the NullReferenceException came from trying to spit out e.InnerException.Message... Anyway certificate doesnt get added, but i get this error: Something went wrong when adding bindings: Access is denied. (0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). Any idea how to fix? Where is the access denied? Certificate is in WebHosting in certificate store.

Comment: Tried doing Step1 in this guide https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1129/37/access-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-e_accessdenied, but still same error. I cannot add to Personal store (step 2). Need to use WebHosting.

Comment: You can easily miss permissions required, https://halfblood.pro/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6

Comment: @Ojs do you see a corresponding message for access denied in the event viewer? Maybe it can give us some more information on what’s being accessed

Comment: Hi. Sorry for answering late. Didnt find out of this one. Didnt see any errors in event viewer either..